# how is cmake's _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS set/configured/influenced? (boost libraries not found)

Tags: boost, cmake

I worked through
    [CMake no longer finds static Boost libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020736/cmake-no-longer-finds-boost-libraries)
and 
    [CMake not finding Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280823/cmake-not-finding-boost)
and some of the other related questions.

I've the same problem, but none of the solutions are suitable for me.

running `cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON .` leads to

```
Building external libraries
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:476 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:478 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:480 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = ON
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:482 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME =
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:484 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS =
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:486 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS =
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:538 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:540 ]   BOOST_ROOT =
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:542 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR =
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:544 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR =
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:546 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:639 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/local/include/boost-1_54/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:663 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.54.0
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:739 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc43
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:749 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:792 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:794 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /usr/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:842 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS = /usr/local/include/boost-1_54/lib;/usr/local/include/boost-1_54/../lib;/usr/local/include/boost-1_54/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
```

Boost version and boost headers are found, the static libraries aren't.
they are all located in `/usr/local/lib64` but this path isn't included in `_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS`.

I'm using `cmake version 2.8.12.2` on `sles11 sp2 x86_64`.

Question is: how is cmake's **_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS** set/configured/influenced?

**UPDATE**

In fact I had two problems, one solved by the answer below, the second was a wrong

`guessed _boost_COMPILER = -gcc43`

which I could solve via
`SET( Boost_COMPILER -gcc48)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the global property `FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS` is set to true before calling `find_package(Boost)`, i.e.:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS TRUE)
```

This should make the `find_library` call in CMake's boost module honor the `/usr/local/lib64` directory.

Comment: Explicitly stating what is in the documentation, if `find_library` is looking in `/usr/local/lib/package`, by setting `FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS` to true, it will look in `/usr/local/lib64/package`, `/usr/local/lib/package/64`, and `/usr/local/lib64/package/64` for your libraries.